# Почему в WordPress VisualComposer не выводится слайдер по шорткоду

Tags: wordpress, slider, wordpress-плагины, шорткод, visual-composer

Страница сделана с помощью плагина visual composer, вставляю шорт-код метаслайдера в html элемент, выводится просто текст шорткода а-ля `[metaslider id=85]`. В чем может быть проблема и как решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что Visual Composer не обрабатывает шорткоды в html-блоках. Используйте текстовые блоки для вставки шорткодов.

Comment: Спасибо =) Не люблю эти пейдж билдеры

Comment: Ну, их можно и не любить, но пользователю они потом сильно упрощают жизнь. Доводилось переводить сайт с "голого" WP на билдер, так клиент рыдал от восторга - как ему теперь удобно все править))

Comment: Ну это да, собственно для удобства обычных юзеров всё это дело и придумано